# Can I redirect output from TPAGE

Tags: template-toolkit

I want **tpage** to redirect the output to a different file.
The redirect filter seems almost to do what I want but when I use it I get :

> redirect error - OUTPUT_PATH is not
>   set

Can I set OUTPUT_PATH using tpage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this doesn't seem to be possible at the moment. what you could do is apply [this patch](http://www.mail-archive.com/templates@template-toolkit.org/msg09511.html) to tpage / tpage.bat, and specifiy the output_path on the command line then, like

```
tpage --output_path=DIR [files]
```

Comment: Thanks - that does what I want.